# How to get source code from peers

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, sip, decompiling

I just want to have a java sip application to run in eclipse but I have'nt found a way yet.  I tried various `decompilers` but none of them completed their work without any `problems`. Is there any way to copy the code `of a jar` to an eclipse project or did someone `find` the source for "peers"?  http://peers.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You read the page you linked to... "Peers source code is now hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/ymartineau/peers ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://github.com/ymartineau/peers hosts the source code as [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has pointed out correctly

Answer (score 0):

Jitsi is an audio/video Internet phone and instant messenger written in Java. It supports some of the most popular instant messaging and telephony protocols such as SIP, Jabber/XMPP (and hence Facebook and Google Talk), AIM, ICQ, MSN, Yahoo! Messenger.
[Jitsi source code](https://jitsi.org/Development/VersionControl)